# RSQLite: binding sets and scalars in the same select query

Tags: sql, database, r, prepared-statement, rsqlite

How can I pass both a scalar and a set of values in the `bind.data` parameter of `dbGetQuery()` for an SQL statement like

```
select * from tst where x = ? and y in (?)
```

Here's what I tried:

```
> library("RSQLite")
> c <- dbConnect (SQLite())
> dbGetQuery(c, "create table tst (x int, y int)")
> dbGetQuery(c, "insert into tst values (?, ?)", data.frame(x=c (1,2,1,2), y=c(3, 4, 5, 6)))
> dbReadTable(c, "tst")
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 1 5
4 2 6
> dbGetQuery (c, "select * from tst where x = ? and y not in (?)", data.frame(x=2, y=I (list(7,6))))
Error in sqliteFetch(rs, n = -1, ...) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'double'
```

From reading the source, any non-data.frame `bind.data` parameter gets forced through `as.data.frame()`, so I guess there's little point in trying anything other than data frames.

**NOTE**: heck, it seems even binding a single set is problematic:

```
> dbGetQuery(c, "select * from tst where y not in (?)", c(7,6))
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 1 5
4 2 6
5 1 3
6 2 4
7 1 5
```

This makes it clear that 2 separate queries (one of which returns 4 and one of which returns 3 results) are send from R; SQLite never sees a set parameter.

**Earlier note**: I want the database engine to filter the appropriate row, i don't want R to compute the cartesian product. In the above example, simply getting rid of `I()` creates a 2-row dataframe (thanks to R's recycling), one of which is the solution. R sends each of these 2 rows to sqlite, and of course the second one matches. But the following shows the SQLite engine doesn't actually receive set parameters with regular data.frames:

```
> dbGetQuery(c, "select * from tst where x in (?) and y in (?)", data.frame(x=c(3,2), y=c(6,7)))
[1] x y
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> dbGetQuery(c, "select * from tst where x in (?) and y in (?)", data.frame(x=c(3,2), y=c(7,6)))
  x y
1 2 6
```

Comment: I also suspect that binding sets for an IN clause may simply not be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you specify `y = I(list(7,6))` instead of `y=c(6,7)`? This seems to work:

```
dbGetQuery (c, 
            "select * from tst where x = ? and y in (?)", 
            data.frame(x=1, y=c(7,6)))
```

You might be looking for `expand.grid`.

```
dbGetQuery (c, 
            "select * from tst where x = ? and y in (?)", 
            expand.grid(x=c(2,3), y=c(7,6)))
```

EDIT: Another option (and it's not pretty) is to substitute the `?` in `R`. Something like the following:

```
dbGetQuerySet <- function(con, statement, ...){
  if (length(list(...)) > 0){
    bind.data <- list(...)[[1]]
    for (set in as.data.frame(bind.data)){  
      statement <- sub('\\?', paste(set, collapse=","), statement)
    }
  }
  sqliteQuickSQL(con, statement, ...)
}
```

Comment: because data.frame recycles short columns; that's equivalent to sending separate queries for (x=1, y=7) and (x=1, y=6). Note that I've changed the question to x=2 -- obviously there are no rows for x=1

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is your desired result?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to learn how to bind sets to parameters, but the example doesn't discriminate... For example, how do you bind 2 sets? This is more complex than I thought

Comment: This computes the result in R! I want the database engine to solve the problem, I don't want R to expand the cartesian product

Comment: OK, I've clarified the question and I'll upvote your answer -- because it does satisfy the original question. But I'm looking for something else.

Comment: Seems this is the best possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting variables to strings:

```
#Variables
myVal_x <- 2
myVal_y <- c(7,6)
#Convert to string
myVal_y <- paste0("(",paste(myVal_y,collapse=","),")")
#Query
dbGetQuery(c, 
            paste("select * from tst where x =",myVal_x,"and y in",myVal_y) 
            )
```

Comment: Sure... but the question was about SQL parameter binding. Though it does seem that binding sets is impossible...